# Are there Enums in Neo-One Smart Contracts?

Tags: typescript, enums, smartcontracts

Is there a possibility to use enums in neo-one smart contracts?
I tried to declare an enum, but got the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf3gT.png)

This is how I declared it:

```
enum testEnum{
  a,
  b,
  c,
}

export class Token extends SmartContract {
  private t: testEnum = testEnum.a;
}
```

It seems that not all typescript types are supported, or I declared it wrong.

Comment: It appears to be valid TypeScript syntax - which version of TypeScript is your project using?

Comment: it is typescript 4.1.2, it seems to be a regular syntax, but I'm getting this error when I try to deploy the contract using "yarn neo-one build"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NEO•ONE TypeScript Smart Contract compiler actually does not currently support enums, which is why you are getting that error. When the compiler runs into an enum declaration (via the `enum` keyword) it just reports an unsupported syntax error. So I recommend just using a plain JS "object" to accomplish the same thing. Like this:

```
const testEnum = {
   a: 'a',
   b: 'b',
   c: 'c',
};
```